# Signal R Server Client "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" missing error

Tags: c#, asp.net, cors, signalr

I'm trying out the Signal R and built a server dll (windows service library/c#) that runs as a Windows Services. I have build also a client application (asp.net web application) to communicate with the server.

But i'm getting always the error(Firefox) "`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.5&connectionData=%5B%5D&_=1482829095207. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).`"

Chrome error "

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)"
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.5&connectionData=%5B%5D&_=1482830200155. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:50259' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.
```

Note: Edge and also IE gives me errors

I have read almost every post about this subject on Stackoverflow, but non of these solutions seems to work.

The code i'm using for the server side:

```
namespace SignalRService
{

    public class StartupConfiguration
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.Map("/signalr", map =>
            {
                map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
                var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
                {
                    EnableDetailedErrors = true,
                    EnableJSONP = true,     
                };
                map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Services.cs

```
public void StartService()
{
    LogMessage("SignalRService started", true);
    Running = true;
    WebApp.Start<StartupConfiguration>(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SignalRServerUrl"]);
}
```

EnvironmentSettings.config:

```
<add key="SignalRServerUrl" value="http://localhost:8080"/>
```

Hubs.cs

```
namespace SignalRService.Hubs
{
    [HubName("TestHub")]
    public class TestHub: Hub
    {
        public static Dictionary<string, List<HubClient>> clients = new Dictionary<string, List<HubClient>>();

        [HubMethodName("Subscribe")]
        public async Task Subscribe(string Id)
        {...... }}
```

ClientSide (Javascript/Jquery)

```
 var signalrHubConnection;
    var signalrHubConnectionProxy;
    var signalRServerUrl = "http://localhost:8080";

    var currentTimeout;
    var count = 0;

    var startSignalRConnection = function () {
        console.log("Start");

        signalrHubConnection = $.hubConnection(signalRServerUrl);
        console.log("Running");
        signalrHubConnection.logging = true;
        signalrHubConnectionProxy = signalrHubConnection.createHubProxy('TestHub');


        console.log("--Subscribe starting");
        signalrHubConnection.start()
            .done(function () {

                signalrHubConnectionProxy.invoke('Subscribe', Id.toString());
                console.log("Subscribe ending");
            })
            .fail(function (test) {
                if (count < 5) {
                    console.log(test.toString());
                    clearTimeout(currentTimeout);
                    currentTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
                        count++;
                        startSignalRConnection();
                    }, 300000); // retry after 5 minutes
                }
            }
        );

        signalrHubConnectionProxy.on('IncomingMessage',
            function (message) {
                console.log("Message = " + message.toString());
            }
        );
    };
```

Test.aspx

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/signalr/jquery.signalr-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Did I something wrong?

Comment: Did you ever work out the solution?

Answer (score 0):

The error implied that the *SignalR url is different from the requesting url* (origin). So, SignalR is on localhost, but your main website (the site that holds the client side example) obviously is accessed using "localhost".

Maybe you're accessing it using an IP (eg http://127.0.0.1/) or your PC name (eg http://badassPC/), whereas they must match under the default SignalR setting. I am pretty certain it doesn't matter if the port is different, and also doesn't matter if they are on the same domain (eg www.mysite.com and signalr.mysite.com)

Note there is a workaround that I wouldn't recommend unless you *really really* know what you're doing as there is a quite serious security risk otherwise: https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#crossdomain